# Azure Download for specific Users

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Project ASP.NET

I will use Azure for my storage. Questions (requirements):

1. In my project I let my registered users download files. But I don't want the user to share this download link to unregistered people (example : the download link what I gave the registered user shall only be downloadable on their computer) .
2. I show only for registered users the download link, the registered users  can download the files that I gave them
3. No one can delete my files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**: This is really up to your app but... if you're giving direct links to blobs in Azure Storage, you would need to protect them with a Shared Access Signature (or policy). This way, you can give someone a link that expires (for example, 10 minutes after you issue the link). Then, if someone gives away the link, it won't work for very long. There's no way to limit a link's use to a specific computer. Now, if you simply stream content from blob to your app, and then from your app to the user, you will probably have a bit more control, since you wouldn't really be generating a reusable link. But this will have downsides (such as running all content through your web tier, requiring more resources in your web tier).

**Question 2:** This is completely up to your app, how you manage assets and present them to a registered user. No way to answer this for you, since we know nothing about your app.

**Question 3:** Azure Storage is accessible by a secret key, which should stay secret, and only you should ever have access to it (for example, it would be used by your code on the server). As long as you don't publish this key anywhere, then nobody would be able to delete your content.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. 1. and 3.  questions I've solved the problems thanks to you.2. question I have a question for you example http://xxx.xx/container/blabla.jpg   is my download link for this picture and I have blabla2.jpg in my container too.When the user try it can he go to the image ?